# Animation for carousel with ng-boostrap and Angular 2

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using the carousel component with [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel). I understand there's an open issue for a proper animation feature that works correctly with the angular 2 component life cycle right now ([Github issue](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/295)).

My question: is there a way to use CSS as a workaround for the animation?

I have put up a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RZFSTkCsKzTx0bqOXJ9G?p=preview) that has fade in effect for the carousel, but not fade out.

```
.carousel-item.active{

    -webkit-animation: fadein 1.4s; 
       -moz-animation: fadein 1.4s; 
        -ms-animation: fadein 1.4s; 
         -o-animation: fadein 1.4s; 
            animation: fadein 1.4s;

}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { 
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Is there a way to make a fade out work? I have tried transition but failed.

Comment: Just a heads up: `@-ms-keyframes` doesn't exist. IE started support straight with regular `@keyframes`. Here's the [MDN page on @keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes#Browser_Compatibility) (no `-ms-` prefix for compatibility) and the [Can I Use? page](http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframes) (IE10 doesn't require prefix)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, answering my own question. The following CSS hack will make the animation work just fine

```
ngb-carousel {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}


.carousel-inner {
    overflow: visible;
}

.carousel-item {
    display: flex !important;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity 1.2s ease-in-out, visibility 1.2s;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
}

.carousel-item.active{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control-prev {
     z-index: 20;
}


.carousel-control-next {
     z-index: 20;
}

.carousel-indicators{
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qunZ8EJ6WNJZmYxEZ50H?p=preview)

Comment: I don't get why I can't get this to work. I even copied your plunks components and css word for word. My ngb carousel is still not using the animations.

Comment: Without looking at your code, it is really hard to tell…

Comment: I copied your code word for word. Is there an extra npm package I have to install other than bootstrap and ng-bootstrap?
I have been messing with this for the longest

Comment: You need to put the styles in the golbal styles.css other than your component's css, Otherwise it won't work. If you have to, you need to manipulate :host and /deep/ to make it work.

Comment: That was it for some odd reason. Global styles worked. But, now my carousel is going down the page instead of replacing the current picture

Comment: Nvm, I have no idea what changed, but it started working out of nowhere

Answer (score 13):

I wanted a fade in/fade out the transition between slides and found a simpler solution to this:

```
::ng-deep {
  .carousel-item {
    transition: opacity 0.7s ease !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .carousel-item.active {
    position: relative !important;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

If you don't want to use `::ng-deep` (it seems that is going to be deprecated, or at least I read so last week in [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)) you can use a global styles file that will reach all classes in all components

Comment: Thanks! I chose not not use ::ng-deep and just threw the 2 classes in my global styles. Works great.

Comment: Great solution!

However if you have links in the carousel items they might interfere. I managed to fix that with adding `visibility` to the mix of transitioned properties:

`
.carousel-item {
  transition: 0.7s ease !important;
  display: block !important;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0
}

.carousel-item.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1
}

`

Answer (score 5):

I managed to create left-to-right slide animation based on your approach. active slide goes out with transition to the right when it loses `.active` and then new `.active` slides in with delayed animation.

though I recommend using `ngx-swiper-wrapper` instead - best angular carousel I found so far (https://idangero.us/swiper/)

```css
.carousel-inner {
  width: 640px;
  height: 240px;
}

.carousel-item {
  padding: 40px 55px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  display: block !important;
}

.carousel-item.active {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: .3s;
  transform: none;
  animation: slideFromLeft .3s;
  animation-delay: .3s;
}

@keyframes slideFromLeft {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've used your answer to improve my implementation of the carousel, although I made the old slides slide away to the right, and the new one slides in from the left https://stackblitz.com/edit/text-ngb-carousel

Answer (score 1):

Here are two animations I used in Angular 9, ng-bootstrap version 6.0.0. Easiest way is to give an entrance animation to `.carousel-item.active`. Animations are taken from [animista.net/play/entrances](https://animista.net/play/entrances). Just make sure you add the `css` to global `styles.css`

**Animation 1**

[image: Animation 1]

```
.carousel-item.active {
    -webkit-animation: flip-in-ver-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
            animation: flip-in-ver-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes flip-in-ver-left {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(80deg);
              transform: rotateY(80deg);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
              transform: rotateY(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  @keyframes flip-in-ver-left {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(80deg);
              transform: rotateY(80deg);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
              transform: rotateY(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

**Animation 2**

[image: Animation 2]

```
.carousel-item.active {
    -webkit-animation: tilt-in-fwd-tr 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
            animation: tilt-in-fwd-tr 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes tilt-in-fwd-tr {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(20deg) rotateX(35deg) translate(300px, -300px) skew(-35deg, 10deg);
              transform: rotateY(20deg) rotateX(35deg) translate(300px, -300px) skew(-35deg, 10deg);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(0) rotateX(0deg) translate(0, 0) skew(0deg, 0deg);
              transform: rotateY(0) rotateX(0deg) translate(0, 0) skew(0deg, 0deg);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  @keyframes tilt-in-fwd-tr {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(20deg) rotateX(35deg) translate(300px, -300px) skew(-35deg, 10deg);
              transform: rotateY(20deg) rotateX(35deg) translate(300px, -300px) skew(-35deg, 10deg);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(0) rotateX(0deg) translate(0, 0) skew(0deg, 0deg);
              transform: rotateY(0) rotateX(0deg) translate(0, 0) skew(0deg, 0deg);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work in angular 7 after tweaking @user3682091 answer
 Hope it helps someone else

Here's my html

```
<div class="section" id="carousel">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">
      <h4>Carousel</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center" style="height: 50vw;">
      <div class="col-12" style="height: 100%; width:100%">
        <ngb-carousel>
          <ng-template ngbSlide>
            <img class="d-block" src="assets/img/bg1.jpg" alt="First slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Nature, United States</h5>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template ngbSlide>
            <img class="d-block" src="assets/img/bg3.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Somewhere Beyond, United States</h5>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template ngbSlide>
            <img class="d-block" src="assets/img/bg4.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Yellowstone National Park, United States</h5>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
        </ngb-carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my style.css file(global css)

```
ngb-carousel {
  //   width: inherit;
  //   height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


.carousel-inner {
  overflow: visible;
}

.carousel-item {
  display: flex !important;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 1.2s ease-in-out, visibility 1.2s;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
}

.carousel-item.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 1.2s ease-in-out, visibility 1.2s;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control-prev {
  z-index: 20;
}


.carousel-control-next {
  z-index: 20;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  z-index: 20;
}
```