# ngb-carousel how can I have animation like fade-in/out between Images/Slides?

Tags: animation, transition, ng-bootstrap

In Ng bootstrap carousel component how can I have transition like fade-in/out between Images/Slides ?

Comment: [look this exact answer like you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567906/animation-for-carousel-with-ng-boostrap-and-angular-2)

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to include a fade in/out like animation.

You have to define the .carousel-item and .carousel-item.active css class as follows:

```
.carousel-item {
    display: block !important;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in-out, visibility 1s;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.carousel-item.active {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;        
    transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in-out, visibility 1s;
    visibility: visible;
    
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Thanks  - this worked when I changed `easy-in-out` to `ease-in-out` in both places.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Jesus answer I came up with a version working for me:

```css
.carousel-item {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

.carousel-item.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-item.carousel-item-right {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-item.active {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1; 
    transition-delay: 0s;       
}

.carousel-item.active.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-item.active.carousel-item-right {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: unset;
}
```

This ensures that coming-in slide fade-in animation starts right after fade-out coming-out slide. Also it fixes a problem with immediate disappearance of coming-out slide by `transform: unset`.