# How to do animation slide left to right and right to left when arrows clicked in ng-carousel angular 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to do animation slide left to right and right to left when  arrows clicked in ngb-carousel angular 4 when I tried below code in style.css but this animation working in the same direction whenever I clicked both arrows

```
.carousel-item {
  /* Force to always be block */
  display: block !important;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition:all  0.2s;
  visibility: hidden;
  float:right;
}

.carousel-item.active {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(0);
  visibility: visible ;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Why would you need custom css for something that doesn't need any custom css?

Comment: what is your question @webdevbooster

Comment: I think I posted that in the previous comment, no?

Comment: Everything you've described is done by native classes. Automatically. Out of the box. So, it appears that you are trying to re-invent the wheel for some reason.

Comment: i need to override can you help like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567906/animation-for-carousel-with-ng-boostrap-and-angular-2    this one is also same

Comment: Aha. So, you actually want to add **different** effects i.e. customize the native behavior. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes i  need  to do absolutely  sir

Comment: Well, in this case, you need to post the *output* HTML for the entire thing because that's what's required in this case.

Comment: hi sir take a look this http://plnkr.co/edit/L3XVu1oXjEPmf1Fu7ypu?p=preview it is working like this in link