# Bootstrap 4 carousel erratic behavior with Angular 6

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am trying to start a native bootstrap 4 carousel from a link-button from angular 6

```
<a class="text-center nav-link mr-3" href="#carousel" role="button" 
data-slide="next" 
(click)="onCarouselStart()">Toggle Slide Show!</a>

 <div 
id="carousel" 
class="carousel slide" 
[attr.data-interval]="carouselInterval" 
[attr.data-ride]="carouselRide" 
>
<!-- The slides -->...... </div>
```

in component:

```
    carouselInterval: any = false;
    carouselRide: string = 'false';

        onCarouselStart() { 


    <!-- 1st option -->
    $('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 3000
    });

   <!-- 2nd option -->
   $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 3000
    });
   $('.carousel').carousel('cycle');


    <!-- 3rd option -->
     this.carouselInterval = 3000;
     this.carouselRide = 'carousel';
              }
```

When I use the 1st option, only the first slide has animation, the rest are showing but no sliding animation.

When I use the 2nd option, slides are animating but somehow this triggers an extra slide and the result is a mess or the carousel starts sliding backwards.[image]

When I use the 3rd option, only the the first slide is animated and then the carousel stops.

Any ideas how to start the carousel from a button normally ?

Comment: it's better to use ng-bootstrap in angular without jquery dependency

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples

Comment: This ng-bootstrap carousel has no animation effect. Anything else?

Comment: you can use CSS transition with it .. chk in SO for answer

Comment: What if I want to animate the slides in both directions with prev/next arrows? how am I supposed to apply 2 different styles to the same css classes? carousel-item, active

Comment: you can use this CSS hack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567906/animation-for-carousel-with-ng-boostrap-and-angular-2

Comment: Yes, you are talking about fadein - out. I have manage to implement that with the native bootstrap carousel. I need scrolling effect. both directions